# How do I "replace" the route in nextjs without triggering reload?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm navigating between routes like:

```
/welcome/article/article-slug-1
/welcome/article/article-slug-2
/welcome/article/article-slug-3
```

The dynamic part is an `article-slug` thing and it becomes a query parameter.

My pages structure:

```
/pages
  /welcome
    /index.js
    /article
      /[slug].js
```

My article list is visible on `/welcome` and `/welcome/article/slug` pages.

Now I do `<Link href='/welcome/article/article-slug-1'/>` and this reloads the page. I can see it in the network tab.

How can I prevent page reloading and still have a dynamic routing?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me previously while working with dynamic routes.

What worked for my case is putting your `href` value in `as` and replacing `href` with `/welcome/article?slug=article-slug-1`

So you should have something like this:

```
<Link 
  as='/welcome/article/article-slug-1'
  href='/welcome/article?slug=article-slug-1'
/>
```